# URL matching regex

Tags: regex, url

I need some help with URL matching regex. I read the regex syntax documentation but it's so complex.

I'm trying to create a URL list for a checkout funnel, how would I set up regex for the following?

```
https://shop.mysite.ca/[unique ID]/checkouts/[unique ID 2]
OR
https://shop.mysite.ca/[unique ID]/checkouts/[unique ID
2]?step=contact_information
```

What I have so far, though not sure how to put the optional parameter "step=contact_information")

```
/^(https:\/\/shop.mysite.ca\/)([\da-z]+)(\/checkouts\/)([\da-z]+)$/
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a "?" to make a group either appear 0 or 1 times, making it optional.

```
/^(https:\/\/shop.mysite.ca\/)([\da-z]+)(\/checkouts\/)([\da-z]+)(\?step=contact_information)?$/
```

Answer (score 0):

this should work

```
^(https:\/\/shop.mysite.ca\/)([\da-z]+)(\/checkouts\/)([\da-z]+)((\?step=contact_information)*)$
```

edit: forgot the `?` and used `*` instead. The other solution by @thomas is a bit better I think

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
^(https:\/\/shop.mysite.ca\/)(\d+.)(\/checkouts)(\/)(\d+.)($|\?\w.+$)
```

If unique ID is composed with non numbers characteres:

```
^(https:\/\/shop.mysite.ca\/)([\da-zA-Z]+.)(\/checkouts)(\/)([\da-zA-Z]+.)($|\?\w.+$)
```